# Unexpected EOF while parsing in Credit check (Luhn’s algorithm)

Tags: python

EDIT: Reminder, before you ask a stupid question on Stackoverflow, be sure to check all braces, semicolons and parentheses!

ORIGINAL POST:
I'm switching from C to python and have a hopefully rather basic question: Why does this return an unexpected EOF while parsing error?
A little background:
This is supposed to check if a credit card number is valid according to Luhn’s algorithm.

```
number = input("Number: ", end="")
numArray = []

for i in number:
    numArray.append(int(i))

firstTime = 0;
secondTime = 0;
cycle2 = 0

for cycle in range(15):
    if(cycle % 2 != 0):
        firstTime += numArray[cycle]*2
    else:
        secondTime += numArray[cycle2]
        cycle2 += 1

print("{} and {}".format(firstTime, secondTime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're missing a trailing `)` in the call to `print`, and the Python interpreter doesn't expect that:

```
print("{} and {}".format(firstTime, secondTime)
                                               ^
```

Fix it to `print("{} and {}".format(firstTime, secondTime))`

Comment: Thanks! That did it :)

Comment: @MichaelKeller I've edited the answer for better representation. Is it acceptable now? :)